# Remove a line of text where the cursor is positioned

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

All my below code remove all blank lines from `TextBox`.
But I want the cursor pointed line to get removed when clicked on button.

```
'First method
TextBox2.Lines = TextBox2.Lines.Where(Function(l) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)).ToArray()
Dim count = TextBox2.Lines.Length

'Second method
Dim tmp() As String = TextBox2.Text.Split(CChar(vbNewLine))
TextBox2.Clear()
For Each line As String In tmp
    If line.Length > 1 Then
        TextBox2.AppendText(line & vbNewLine)
    End If
Next

'Third method
Dim SearchIn = Me.TextBox2.Text
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(SearchIn)
Me.TextBox2.Text = sb.Replace(vbCrLf + vbCrLf, vbCrLf).ToString

'Fourth method
TextBox2.Text = Regex.Replace(TextBox2.Text, "(?<Text>.*)(?:[\r\n]?(?:\r\n)?)", "${Text} ") + "/n"

TextBox2.Text = Replace(TextBox2.Text, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: `Cursor.Hide` maybe?

Comment: Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a line of text from a `TextBoxBase` derived control (TextBox, RichTextBox), you first have to identify the correct line.

You can't use the [.Lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.Lines);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) property if the Text is wrapped, because it will return the line number relative to the unwrapped text.

You can get the current wrapped line with [GetLineFromCharIndex()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getlinefromcharindex?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.GetLineFromCharIndex);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2). The Integer parameter is the current caret position, referenced by the `SelectionStart` property.

The first character index of this line is retured by [GetFirstCharIndexFromLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getfirstcharindexfromline?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2).

Then, find the current line lenght, identifying the first line feed. Add the lenght of the line feed symbol(s) to include them in the computed lenght.

Note that `TextBox` controls use [Environment.Newline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Environment.NewLine);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) to generate a line feed ("`\r\n`"), while `RichTextBox` controls use only a line feed ("`\n`").

This will remove any line where the caret is currently positioned:
(If you just want to allow blank lines to be removed, check whether the line lenght is `< 3`).

```
Dim CurrentPosition As Integer = TextBox2.SelectionStart
Dim CurrentLine As Integer = TextBox2.GetLineFromCharIndex(CurrentPosition)
Dim LineFirstChar As Integer = TextBox2.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(CurrentLine)
Dim LineLenght As Integer = TextBox2.Text.
                            IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, LineFirstChar) - LineFirstChar +
                            Environment.NewLine.Length
If LineLenght <= 0 Then Return

TextBox2.Select(LineFirstChar, LineLenght)
TextBox2.SelectedText = TextBox2.SelectedText.Remove(0)
TextBox2.SelectionLength = 0
TextBox2.SelectionStart = If(CurrentPosition < TextBox2.Text.Length, LineFirstChar, TextBox2.Text.Length)
TextBox2.Focus()
```

This will instead remove the whole paragraph that contains the caret:

```
Dim CurrentPosition As Integer = TextBox2.SelectionStart
Dim ParagraphFirstIndex As Integer = TextBox2.Text.
                                     LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine, CurrentPosition) +
                                                 Environment.NewLine.Length
Dim LineFeedPosition As Integer = TextBox2.Text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, ParagraphFirstIndex)
LineFeedPosition = If(LineFeedPosition > -1, LineFeedPosition + Environment.NewLine.Length, TextBox2.Text.Length)

Dim LineLenght As Integer = LineFeedPosition - ParagraphFirstIndex
If LineLenght <= 0 Then Return

TextBox2.Select(ParagraphFirstIndex, LineLenght)
TextBox2.SelectedText = TextBox2.SelectedText.Remove(0)
TextBox2.SelectionLength = 0
TextBox2.SelectionStart = If((CurrentPosition < TextBox2.Text.Length), ParagraphFirstIndex, TextBox2.Text.Length)
TextBox2.Focus()
```

Comment: -> i have one more query.if possible can you share your email id so that i can send you my qery or shall i drop over here my query?

Comment: My query is:  1)I have browsed image folder and browsed textfile folder.but i want to display only image in listbox. And when suppose "data.jpg" image is clicked the "data.txt" file should get opened automatically in "TextBox1"

Comment: i am new over here so i dont know where is "accepted" option.I have posted new question and its link is "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50735259/open-data-txt-when-clicked-on-data-jpg-in-listbox"   So, please Jim help me out in that query also or please give your emial id so that i can share you the link or mail you directly all my queries as first time i posted here and you gave me the 100% working solution. Thats very good of you to help me and thanks for helping.

Comment: @snehal jagtap  I have seen your new question. Follow the advice that has been given to you there. That question is "Too Broad" as it is now. It has 2 close votes and it will be downvoted, as will probably be downvoted any answer to that question. You have to try to focus on a single problem at the time, posting enough code so that someone can use that code to reproduce the problem and fix it. Or give you some advice using a sample code. If you instead dump all of your code there, you're saying "I have a lot of issues here, solve them for me". It's quite probable that you won't get an answer.

Comment: is there any solution for any of the two queries being mentioned there? and i did not find any advice over there?